# Changing packaging based on active profile in pom

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a project which I compile with maven. I have different profiles declared in pom.xml.
For some of these profiles, I prefer building a war, and for other profiles I prefer a jar. I use to manually edit the pom.xml file and change packaging variable to either

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

or

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

before doing a

```
$ mvn clean package -Pchosenprofile
```

How can I tell mvn the packaging corresponding to each profile so I don't need to edit pom.xml?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

If you want to use profile you can use something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    ..
    <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>webapp</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>batch</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            </properties>
                </profile>
          </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: You can omit the default profile by just adding the property to the global properties. If the alternative profile is loaded, the default property will be overwritten.

Comment: Initially I thought this didn't work in a multi-module project, but it seems to :-)

Comment: That's rocks man, to generate with the same pom.xml a docker image or war for local install. Great.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the [attachClasses](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#attachClasses) configuration setting of the war plugin? This simple setting would let you build both a war and a jar (by default with the classifier "classes") in a single maven execution.

Comment: This is not wat I had in mind, but it actually solves my problem and it's fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.

Two alternatives I can think of:

- have two separate modules for packaging, and call one of those depending on profile
- have your module in war and tweak the lifecycle (include/exclude build steps) depending on profile to produce your jar or your war

I like the second approach better - a build server would probably build both, and a developer would use the proper profiles/settings to skip the unwanted type.

Comment: Thanks. I like the attachClasses approach better because it's simpler, but I might have to resort to something like this in a more complex situation.

Comment: attachClasses (or similar) is what I had in mind for bullet 2 - basically a war is a jar with extra stuff - and maven is perfectly capable of producing both at the same time