# Is there any way to change mywebapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar from attachClasses configuration in maven-war-plugin to mywebapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jar, war

According to [maven-war-plugin FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached),

> If you can't move the classes to another project, you can deploy the classes and resources included in your webapp as an "attached" artifact, with a classifier, by using the following configuration:

```
<project>
  ...
  <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

> This will result in two artifacts being deployed: **mywebapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war and mywebapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar**.

Is there any way possible that I could get **mywebapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar instead of mywebapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar**?

**Update:** :

I want both war as well as jar to be generated. Though I am able to do this by applying profiles as mentioned in [Changing packaging based on active profile in pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247720/changing-packaging-based-on-active-profile-in-pom). But I am curious to know about above question.

Comment: Why would you like having a war type packaged into a jar file? This sounds a little bit strange?

Comment: I want war as well as jar. I knew that from same pom.xml, both war and jar should not be generated, but I have been asked to do so. I have been following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247720/changing-packaging-based-on-active-profile-in-pom

Comment: Hi @ritesh, did you check the XML I put in my answer, just to know why it didn't met your needs ? Thanks !

Comment: Hi @Guillaume Darmont: I have asked very specific question with respect to maven-war-plugin. I have already created war and jar as mentioned in Update section. I am very thankful to all the replies and have upvoted to all of them. Hope I have answered your question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **no**, you can't.

By looking at the maven-war-plugin sources, in [WarMojo.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-war-plugin-2.4/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/war/WarMojo.java?view=markup) (line 292), you can see that you cannot meet your requirement by simply modifying the **maven-war-plugin** configuration:

```
    protected static File getTargetFile( File basedir, String finalName, String classifier, String type )
    {
        if ( classifier == null )
        {
            classifier = "";
        }
        else if ( classifier.trim().length() > 0 && !classifier.startsWith( "-" ) )
        {
            classifier = "-" + classifier;
        }

        return new File( basedir, finalName + classifier + "." + type );
    }
```

Since the `classesClassifier` parameter is `"classes"` by default, you have no chance to modify this behavior: `classifier` will never be `null`.

Either you rename the file after its generation, or you modify the source code of the **maven-war-plugin**, and use it as a custom plugin.

As a final consideration, it is not advisable to have a null *classesClassifier*: it could be misleading. I do not know your project requirement though.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please attach link/name of class corresponding to mentioned code. Thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 2):

The closest approach to what you want to do is to use `<classesClassifier>`

as

```
    <project>
  ...
  <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
          <classesClassifier>someClassifier</classesClassifier>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

but this approach will always put the classifier as `your_jar-classifier.jar` and if you create and empty or spaced tag, it will default to `-classes`

On the other hand, by using `archiveClasses` instead of `attachClasses` you will find the JAR just as you want it inside war's `WEB-INF\lib` (without the classifier), but no `WEB-INF\classes` will be generated.

Comment: Both the cases are not my requirement :) I want war as well as jar with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Try to configure your webapp's `pom.xml` using the following `<build>` section, to see if it fits your needs :

```
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>create-jar</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-jar</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <artifacts>
              <artifact>
                <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
              </artifact>
            </artifacts>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
...
```

This section asks Maven to explicitly create a `jar`, then it attaches the created `jar` to the build so that the `install` phase can copy the generated artifact into the local repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>                    
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Combining some of the ideas mentioned above seems to work for me. The <archiveClasses> ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423626/maven-war-plugin-ignores-archiveclasses)) causes the required JAR to be generated within the WAR file and the attach-artifact goal extracts that file as an artifact.

Answer (score 0):

Maven's general philosophy is that one POM generates one artifact. That would mean the cleanest, most "Maveny" way to get the Jar out of your project is to separate your Java code and the Webapp items into two modules grouped together by a parent project.

So a potential project hierarchy could be:

```
mywebapp-parent/ -> Contains all dependency info, project version
  mywebapp/ -> Creates Jar
  mywebapp-web/ -> Depends on mywebapp, Creates War
```