# maven-war-plugin ignores <archiveClasses>

Tags: maven, war, maven-war-plugin

The [`<archiveClasses>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#archiveClasses) option has no effect.

Running `mvn clean compile war:exploded` produces a war directory with .class files in the `classes` directory, and they are not archived into a jar in the `lib` directory neither. `war:war` produces same result.

Plugin configuration:

```
...
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
      <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Workarounds?

Maven version 3.3.3, maven-war-plugin version 2.6.

JIRA ticket – https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-355

This is the project in question: https://bitbucket.org/dmos62/raudondvaris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is you should move the plain configuration into a `pluginManagement` [block like this](https://github.com/khmarbaise/so-questions/tree/master/so-5):

```xml
 <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <configuration>
            <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

If you do the above the classes will be created within the war archive by using: `mvn clean compile war:war`

```
~/ws-git/so-questions/so-5 (master)$ unzip -t target/web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
Archive:  target/web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
    testing: META-INF/                OK
    testing: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF     OK
    testing: WEB-INF/                 OK
    testing: WEB-INF/classes/         OK
    testing: WEB-INF/lib/             OK
    testing: WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar   OK
    testing: WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.1.jar   OK
    testing: WEB-INF/lib/web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar   OK
    testing: WEB-INF/web.xml          OK
    testing: META-INF/maven/com.soebes.examples.so/web/pom.xml   OK
    testing: META-INF/maven/com.soebes.examples.so/web/pom.properties   OK
    testing: META-INF/INDEX.LIST      OK
No errors detected in compressed data of target/web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war.
```

This will also working for your call `mvn clean compile war:exploded`.

```
   └── web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        ├── META-INF
        └── WEB-INF
            ├── classes
            ├── lib
            │   ├── commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
            │   ├── commons-io-1.1.jar
            │   └── web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
            └── web.xml
```

The reason for this behaviour is simply cause by using a goal like `war:war`, or `war:exploded` there will be no life cycle started which means the configuration in the pom is not taken into account. If you like having a configuration for your command line calls you can do this by using a special configuration for command line calls like this (The id `default-cli` is the important part):

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId...>
        <artifactId...>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              .....
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

which means having a special configuration for command line calls. Starting with Maven 3.3.1 it is possible having more than one configuration for command line calls by using it like:

```xml
<project...>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>first-cli</id>
            <configuration>
                 ....
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>second-cli</id>
            <configuration>
                 ....
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This can be used by maven via the following:

```
mvn plugin:goal@second-cli
mvn plugin:goal@first-cli
```

See also the [release notes for Maven 3.3.1](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2015/03/17/apache-maven-3-dot-3-1-features/).

Comment: I tried your [sample maven project](https://github.com/khmarbaise/so-questions/tree/master/so-5) and it worked; however, none of these suggestions worked on my setup. Also <pluginManagement> had no effect on your setup, if removed `mvn clean compile war:exploded` still works properly. I will make my setup publicly available.

Comment: Remove the definition for `<outputDirectory>` cause it is not needed. Why have you configured that?

Comment: I have checked your project and if you remove `<outputDirectory>` it works as expected. Furthermore i don't know why you have bound versions-maven-plugin to compile phase which tooks ages (as expected) but does not really make sense. Apart from that you defined many dependencies with `<optional>false</optional>` which can be omitted, cause it's default.

Comment: Send you an pull request which clean up the problems.

Comment: Thank you. Removing `<outputDirectory>` fixed my problem. Can you explain why? I'm sending you this picture as [a sign of my gratitude](http://i.imgur.com/pAMlELC.jpg). My configurations are a bit awkward, because they are largely automatically generated. I can't remember where the outputDirectory option came from.