# Maven Packing Type Based on Profile

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am using a found example on stackoverflow that dynamically changes the packaging type based on profile

[Changing packaging based on active profile in pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247720/changing-packaging-based-on-active-profile-in-pom/15134587#15134587)

This is a snippet of my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.scene7.is.qa</groupId>
<artifactId>jorogumo</artifactId>
<packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>
...
<profile>
    <id>JorogumoReportingWebApp</id>
    <properties>
        <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
        <final.name>jorogumo</final.name>
    </properties>
...
```

Based on the upvotes from the answer link above I am assuming this should work, but I receive an error when cleaning

```
$ mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.scene7.is.qa:jorogumo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT     (/Users/xyz/working/_workspaces/Scene7/java/jorogumo/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: ${packaging.type} @ line 10, column 13
```

Am I missing something? Or is this the wrong approach?
My end goal is to share common java classes between the web app and the command line jar.

Comment: This seems wrong. Modularity looks to be the way you should do that. Something like 1 JAR module for business logic, 1 WAR module for the WebApp, one JAR (or other) module for the CLI app. The 2 lasts depending on the first.

Comment: BTW, the linked issue solution works only because there is a default value for the property, through a default profile. But still looks a wrong path ;)

Comment: @Tome Thanks! I took the idea of creating a default value for package.type and that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a default packing.type property with a value:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.scene7.is.qa</groupId>
<artifactId>jorogumo</artifactId>
<packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

...

<properties>
    <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>JorogumoReportingWebApp</id>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            <final.name>jorogumo</final.name>
        </properties>
...
```