# Maven project with "war" packaging: how to create JAR with maven-jar-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin

I have a Maven project, which builds a WAR (a REST web service running on Tomcat). In pom.xml I have

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Some classes are used in another, separate project. I build these classes using the [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/), which is configured followingly:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>models</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
                <includes>
                    <include>com/initech/middleware/application/conversion/*</include>
                    <include>com/initech/middleware/error/*</include>
                    <!-- other includes removed for example brevity -->
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- removed for example brevity -->
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-a-jar</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Currently I create the JAR file by changing the "packaging" option in the pom.xml manually from "war" to "jar" and running

```
mvn install
```

which creates the JAR file and installs it in my local repository. However, I would like to do this without having to manually edit the pom.xml file each time before building the JAR file. I have tried using the option "-Dpackaging=jar", but this did not help.

Is it possible to create the JAR file as configured with the maven-jar-plugin just by running maven in the command line, and if yes, how?

Comment: Feasible to split your project into 2 modules? one jar and one war... or use a maven profile to change the packaging?

Comment: I would like to avoid splitting the project. But using a profile sounds good, I was not aware that this is a possibility - thanks. Searching for this I found a good example here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247720/changing-packaging-based-on-active-profile-in-pom I'll try this out right away.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped :)

Comment: It worked. :) If you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Perhaps we can just mark this question as a duplicate, are you happy with that?

Comment: That's ok, no problem.